# Do I see tweets from users that I don't follow, even if they follow me?

Tags: twitter

If people are following me, but I'm not following them back, do their tweets show up on my Twitter timeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way Tweets turn up in your timeline is if someone you are following Tweets or retweets.

If someone is following you then *your* Tweets show up in *their* timeline - not the other way round.

Tweets from people you're not following will turn up in your timeline if they mention you (@Lucy) - but with the latest reorganisation of the Twitter web interface they'll probably only appear on the @connect tab.

Comment: Oh okay, so does that mean any celebrities I'm following (that aren't following me back) , can't see my tweets unless I mention them?

Comment: @Lucy - That's right.

Comment: Oh right okay, thank you for your help :)

Comment: There is a good article on Twitter's Support site called [Twitter Basics](https://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics)

Comment: @Lucy If the answer helped you.. You should mark it as correct so others will learn as well

Comment: @Dez - [Twitter Basics](https://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics) link is dead.